# Am I structuring my IF statement incorrectly in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm doing some computer science homework and am trying to learn some basic python. I'm trying to do an IF statement, but I keep getting a syntax error (python version 3.3.3, by the way). Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please note that although my mistake is most likely in the IF statement it could also be elsewhere. Thanks.

```
print ("Hello. What is your name?")
print("")
name = input()
print("")
print("Hello ", name, ". What lesson do you have next?")
print("")
lesson = input()
print("")
print("I hate ", lesson, ". You're rubbish.")
wait = input()
print("...")
wait = input()
print("...")
wait = input()
print("...")
wait = input()
print("")
print("Do you like me? If you love me, type 1. If you hate me, type 2. If you're inbetween, type 3.")
print("")
emotion = input()
print("")
if emotion == 1:
    print ("Awwwwwww.")
    print ("")
    else:
        if emotion == 2:
        print ("Yeah well I don't like you either.")
        print ("")
        else:
            if emotion == 3:
            print ("Yeah OK fair enough")
            print ("")
            else:
                print("I said type 1, 2 or 3. I'm going now.")
                print("")
print("I'm going now. Goodbye friend.")
print("")
wait = input()
quit()
```

Comment: Post the actual error messages you get

Comment: All I get is "Syntax error". It won't tell me what.

Comment: How are you running it? You should at least get a traceback.

Answer (score 1):

`else` always has to be indented to the same level as the corresponding `if`:

```
if emotion == 1:
    print ("Awwwwwww.")
    print ("")
else:
    if emotion == 2:
        # etc.
```

Next, you can use `elif` here:

```
if emotion == 1:
    print ("Awwwwwww.")
    print ("")
elif emotion == 2:
    # etc.
```

Next, I'd not use `if...elif...` here at all; you'd use a list or mapping instead:

```
emotions = ['', 'Awwwwwww.', "Yeah well I don't like you either.", ...]
print(emotions[emotion])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've added your elif suggestion (since I'm still a beginner and don't understand the other one) but now I'm getting an "Invalid Syntax" error for the colon next to the 2 for emotion == 2:

Comment: @user2627595: then you have another error somewhere. Do you actually have a suite (an indented block of statements) under the `elif` for example?

Answer (score 0):

Python is indentation sensitive.
The indentation of the `else` must be the same as the indentation of the `if`:

```
if emotion == 1: # 1
    <code>
    if <condition>: # 2
         <code>
    elif <condition>: # 2
         <code>
    else: # 2
         <code>
else: # 1
    <code>
```

The #1 `else` belongs to the #1 `if`. The #2 `elif` and `else` belong to the #2 `if`.